# Replace " by ' with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file call `xxxx.txt` and I want in a var the line start with `Sentencia`, but " replaced by '.

```
$ cat xxxx.txt
>Ejecutor: Ezequiel
>Jira: 13226
>Origen (PROD/CUA/ACE/PROD6/DEV): PROD
>Destino (PROD/CUA/ACE/PROD6/DEV): CUA
>Sentencia: select * from pricing_user.prc_promotions where fec_baja is NULL and end_date 
between NOW() and adddate(NOW(), 30) and werks in ("6027", "0006", "0055", "6785")
>Tabla Destino: pricing_user.prc_promotions
```

I am using awk, but I can not do it.

```
$ var=$(awk -F": " '{if ($1 == "Sentencia") print $2} {gsub("\"","\'",$0)}' xxxx.txt)
> ^C
```

Comment: Do your lines start with `>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bullet proof version would be:

```
awk 'match($0,/^Sentencia: */){gsub("\042","\047"/); print substr($0,RLENGTH+1)}'
```

We make use of the [octal notation](http://www.asciitable.com/) as this is the one which is supported by Posix (See section regular expressions of the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04)).

I avoid the usage of `FS=":"` as there could be an extra `:` in the respective line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F": " '{if ($1 == "Sentencia") {gsub("\042","\047",$2);print}}' $wkdir/xxxx.txt
```

I replace the double quote by `\042` and single quote by `\047` (octal equivalent)

```
$ awk -F": " '{if ($1 == "Sentencia") {gsub("\042","\047",$2);print}}' $wkdir/MigrarDatosTablas.txt
Sentencia select * from pricing_user.prc_promotions where fec_baja is NULL and end_date between NOW() and adddate(NOW(), 30) and werks in ('6027', '0006', '0055', '6785')
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the others answers, you could also write your program to an awk file and, with the shell not interfering, use the quotes as-is:

```
$ cat program.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=":"               # set the delimiter
}
/^>Sentencia:/ {         # match the beginning
    gsub(/"/,"'",$0)     # <- LOOK HERE
    print $2             
}
$ awk -f program.awk file
 select * from pricing_user.prc_promotions where fec_baja is NULL and end_date between NOW() and adddate(NOW(), 30) and werks in ('6027', '0006', '0055', '6785')
```

I'm going to overlook some other problems in the code as others already have pointed them out.